# Remove a Policy Resource with Powershell

Tags: powershell, information-management, records-management

I am having trouble deploying a Custom Retention Policy, and have ended up with a hanging policy resource that is keeping me from activating the retention policy.  I was wondering if there was a way to remove this in powershell.  The way this is done in C# is:

```
using Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.InformationPolicy;
...
PolicyResourceCollection.Delete("PolicyResourceID");
```

Is there a way to do this in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

[Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.InformationPolicy.PolicyResourceCollection]::Delete("PolicyResourceID");
```

Comment: Thank you, sir.  Worked like a charm.  Wish powershell had more succinct access to other assemblies, though.